# Manually fetch values from asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a FormView control with Two text Boxes. Data source for the Controls is an ObjectDataSource

I want to fetch these values from both text boxes, create a **User** object and pass it to ObjectDataSource, which has an input  method that accept a User object

I think I have to do it in

```
protected void ObjectDataSourceUsert_Inserting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
        {  
            // string _userName = FormViewUserDetails. ?
            // string _password = FormViewUserDetails. ?

            User user = new User {UserName = _userName, Password = _password};
            e.InputParameters.Add(user);    
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to find the controls inside the formview, you can use

```
TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)MyFormView.Row.FindControl("controlID");
```

Comment: It is not the control I need but the value It holds, can I avoid first creating a TextBox to get its value ?

Comment: @adsi: the value of a `TextBox` is found in its `Text` property. Note that the `TextBox` object is not created (in normal cases) by the code above; the code merely fetches the `TextBox` object for you.

Comment: Thanks mate i have figured it out.